# glGetBufferSubData() not returning any data?

Tags: c++, opengl

I've tried running the code in the example below. However, after `glGetBufferSubData` is called data retains it's default values and does not get the values stored in `bufferObject[0]` which are equal to the values in vertices. Am I using `glGetBufferSubData` incorrectly?

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(arrayObject);
glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObject[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObject[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertices * sizeof(Vector3), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

Vector3 *data = new Vector3();

glGetBufferSubData(bufferObject[0], 0, numVertices * sizeof(Vector3), data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
glGetBufferSubData(bufferObject[0], 0, numVertices * sizeof(Vector3), data);
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ nope
```

The `target` parameter of [`glGetBufferSubData()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetBufferSubData.xhtml) should specify a binding point, not a buffer object.  Try `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` instead:

```
glGetBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, numVertices * sizeof(Vector3), data);
```

Comment: Or `glGetNamedBufferSubData` if DSA is your thing.